# Not able to pass props.field to action using dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react.I'm doing a theatre seat map page.Here I recieve seatMap as props from parent component.I need to update this seat map so I just edited the props(which I'm doubtful is the right way to implement the code.In order to update seat map should I create a copy this props  and edit that copy and dispatch action passing this edited copy as argument?) and tried pass it to action

```
const SeatMap = (props) => {
      console.log("prop.seatInfo is ",props.seatInfo)
      console.log("prop.seatInfo isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ",props.seatInfo)
      const accountDetails = useSelector(state => console.log("Redux state is ",state));
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    
      const changeStatus=(seat)=>{
        console.log("change status called with seat",seat)
        seat.status="selected"
    dispatch({
      modifySeatMap(props.seatInfo);
    })
      }
        return (
           <View>
               
               <View><Text style={[styles.SelectSeatsText]}>Select Seats</Text></View>
                 {/* <View>
               <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/screen.png')} style={[{width:"100%",alignSelf:"center"}]} />
               </View>  */}
               <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View >{props.seatInfo.blocks.map((block,index)=><View style={{height:block.height,width:block.width,borderWidth:2,left:block.left}}><Text style={{alignSelf:"center"}}>{block.name+" "+`\u20B9`+block.price}</Text></View>)}</View>
       <View style={{position:"absolute"}} >{props.seatInfo.blocks.map((block,index)=>block.seats.map((seat,index)=><View style={[{height:seat.height,width:seat.width,borderWidth:1,borderColor:"green",position:"absolute",left:seat.left,
      top:seat.top,justifyContent:"center"},seat.status=="reserved"?{backgroundColor:"#FFAA00"}:'',seat.status=="selected"?{backgroundColor:"#00FF5D"}:'',seat.status=="unavailable"?{backgroundColor:"black"}:'']}><TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{changeStatus(seat);}}><Text style={styles.seatText}>{seat.name}</Text></TouchableOpacity></View>))}</View>
    </ScrollView>
    
          </View> 
    
        );
    }
```

but `modifySeatMap(props.seatInfo);` this line causes the error props is declared but it's value is never used
[image]

what am I doing wrong ? any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The curly brackets on line 18 and 20 are redundant. Just delete them:

```
dispatch(
  modifySeatMap(props.seatInfo);
)
```